# Можно ли сделать подсказку только по городам , или по странам ymaps SuggestView?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Можно ли сделать подсказку только по городам , или по странам  ymaps SuggestView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого Яндекс выделил сервис подсказок в отдельный сервис — [Геосаджест](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geosuggest/). У него в запросе есть [параметр — **types**](https://yandex.ru/dev/geosuggest/doc/ru/request#:%7E:text=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8.-,types,-%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B2), который как раз и определяет тип искомого объекта. В том числе там есть вариант **country** — страна и **locality** — село, аул, город, жилой комплекс, садовое товарищество.